# Call the program with exactly one argument result

Tags: java

Keep getting error of "Call the program with exactly one argument!", but am unsure where I need to make changes to run the program correctly. Thanks!!

```
class Main {

    private static ArrayList<ArrayList<int[]>> list;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.out.println("Call the program with exactly one argument!");
            System.out.println("argument 1: path to map file");
            System.out.println("argument 2: path to airports file");
            System.out.println("argument 3: path to flights file");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
```

Comment: The program needs to be called with three parameters, e.g. `java Main map_file airports_file flights_file`

Comment: Your message is also wrong, as you require calling the program with three arguments. However, given you don't show how you run your program, we can't really answer this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your main method with three parameters as you point in your code (`args.length`). In order to call your method via command line:

```
- java Main.java param1 param2 param3
```

If you want to call `main` method using only one parameter, then you'll get `println` messages you write.